# What's difference between a "stagnum" and "lacuna"?

Tags: classical-latin, synonyms

I'm trying to give title to a earth (no pluvial) water "puddle" of  photo

[image]

[image: STAGNO]

Comment: Is your question about the difference between *stagnum* and *lacuna* (in your title) or the most appropriate Latin term for the pools in your photos? I haven't thought too hard about it but it may well be those questions have different answers (especially for an obviously man-made pool like in your first photo).

Comment: Well, knowing the difference between both terms requires a prior definition of both nouns, which allows to infer the appropriate noun for the image.

Answer (score 10):

It could be both a *lacuna* and a *stagnum*, both words are appropriate.

With this kind of question, a dictionary of synonyms will often help. These are dictionaries specialized in laying out the differences between words with similar meaning. A well known and online accessible one is Ludwig von Döderlein's, easily available online in the English translation by S. H. Arnold (1875). [Here's what it has to say:](https://latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries/?t=do280)

> **Lacuna** denotes, in poetical language, any standing water, from a sea to a pool; **lacus** and **stagnum** are collections of standing water kept sound and fresh by their own springs, or by ebbing and flowing; **lacus** (liquere) is large enough to bring to mind the image of the open sea, in opp. to the main sea, like λίμνη; **stagnum**, like a pond, not so large as to resemble a lake, in opp. to a stream, like τέναγος; …

The entry also discusses *palus, uligo, lama* and *lustrum*, but these all seem inappropriate.

Forecellini fleshes out the difference between *stagnum* and *lacus* in his [entry on the latter](http://www.lexica.linguax.com/forc.php?searchedLG=lacus) thus:

> Differt a *stagno,* quod hoc temporalem habet aquam stagnantem, quae plerumque hieme colligi solet, aestate siccari: sed *lacus* aqua perpetua et perennis est.

So we can rule out *lacus* (which you didn't ask about anyway); the question is whether we can call this a *stagnum* if your garden pond is not “kept sound and fresh” by its own spring or fed by a river, and if it is artificial. I would say yes: for one, your pond is presumably kept sound and fresh somehow; Döderlein mostly appears to write this to delineate the opposition to *paludes, uligines* and similar things, which are corrupted, foul, thick and filthy. Also, the word can clearly be used for artificial ponds, e.g. Ovid ([*Pont* 1, 8](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/ovid/ovid.ponto1.shtml)) reminiscing about *stagna et euripi Virgineusque liquor* of Rome (*Virgineus liquor*, in case you're wondering, is apparently water from the Aqua Virgo, one of the City's aqueducts).

*Lacuna* seems to be a very general word for any body of standing water, big or small, including ponds. I particularly like a quotation found in Forcellini, Palludius about keeping geese: *Si desit fluvius, lacuna formetur* ([*De re rustica*](http://www.forumromanum.org/literature/palladius/agr1.html#30) 1, 30). Palludius is also clearly not a poet (nor does he count as a classical writer), but it does seem to be true that in this sense, *lacuna* is mostly a poetic usage. In sober prose I would prefer *stagnum*.